# # fragment anchor in location header dropped by IE9

Tags: url, internet-explorer-9, anchor, fragment-identifier

I have been testing the location headers below, where a form on index.php submits to an imageupload.php then returns to the page. I included an anchor to return to the form.

Having read previous questions here, this should not cause an error in FireFox or IE but I am finding the fragment is lost in IE9.

```
header("Location: index.php?upload_message=image%20uploaded#".$folder); 
header("Location: http://admin.example.com/index.php?upload_message=image%20uploaded#".$folder);
```

'The location header requires an absolute path per the HTTP specification...' so I tried the second option but this also fails. Could it have something to do with the site being a subdomain?

Comment: because of the 3xx redirect: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/17/url-fragments-and-redirects-anchor-hash-missing.aspx ?

Comment: Correct link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/05/16/url-fragments-and-redirects/